# PHP Query to Show Alert

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal website and I am trying to integrate an API of a control panel I am integrating the login of into the drupal site. In the API I must define a logout link `mywebsite.com/logout` that tells the user he or she has logged out.

However, I want it to go back to the login page and display an alert.

I was hoping there was a way in which I define the logout link in the API as `mywebsite.com/login?=logout` or something like that.

When the user logs out of the control panel, then it sends the user to `mywebsite.com/login?=logout`.

I have HTML code I would like to displayed on the page when the URL includes
`?=logout`. I have the HTML code for the dismissible box that appears on the top of the page already. However, I do not know how to implement it so that it only appears when the URL is `mywebsite.com/login?=logout`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, so, in order to do that, you would need to keep an open connection with every user that visits it. It is not very good idea to do that unless necessary.

Since this is a simple task, PHP can output a simple metacommand in the HTML code, as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourloginscript.php?action=login">
```

That alone will not do the job though, because if the user navigates back the web page will serve the page normally. No. You also need to make the cookie expire after a certain time this can be done like this:

```
// get the $username first, it can be store in the SESSION.
setcookie('username', $username, $Logtime)
```

Remember to set the $Logtime to 300 seconds. Refresh this on every visit to the website, so that the 300 seconds start every time user opens a page. Check the validity of the cookie on every visit to make sure the user is still logged in, With this, you will get the functionality that you want.

Another way to do it, is using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourloginscript.php?action=logout">
```

And simply have the script log the user out at that moment, like this:

```
// Clear the username.
setcookie('username', "", $Logtime)
```

Be aware that this will not work if the user has somehow disabled HTML forwarding, and there are various ways to disable automatic forwarding.

Even another method to do it would be to jave a timer in Javascript to do the job, and forward to a "logout" URL after the time elapses.

I would personally use a combination of them all just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
echo "<script>alert('test');</script>";
}
```

Hope it helps you.